# How to Convert factors to Dates in R

Tags: r

I have a set of dates from this csv file and want to convert them to a date format in R

```
BPL16_17 <- read.csv("BPL16:17.csv") 
attach(BPL16_17)
newdate<-strptime(Date,format =("%Y-%m-%d"))
newdate
```

for newdate i get; [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA...

Comment: Two things 1.  run `str(Date)` to see what R thinks it is and if it is a factor, try: `BPL16_17 <- read.csv("BPL16:17.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` then use either POSIXct or strptime with the format.

Comment: Also, unless there is a good reason to attach the file to a fixed location in the global environment you can address the data frame `BPL16_17` without attaching it ...when you attach an object, unless you detach and reattach, changes are not saved against it, so the `Date` field would remain a factor...

Comment: Problem-aside, that output could benefit from being `.paste()`ed with the **Batman** string. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` inside `read.csv` to read the Date column as a string and not as a factor.

Or, convert the Date column from factor to character using `as.character(BPL16_17$Date)`

Answer (score 0):

Dataset used in example is `flight-data` from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vi530bac7836ch9/airline_delay_2014_1.csv?dl=0) .

```
#read the dataset
df<-read.csv("D:/data/airline_delay_2014_1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)
'data.frame':   471949 obs. of  27 variables:
 $ YEAR             : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
 $ MONTH            : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DAY_OF_MONTH     : int  25 30 24 1 3 4 5 9 13 12 ...
 $ FL_DATE          : chr  "2014-01-25" "2014-01-30" "2014-01-24" "2014-01-01" ...
 $ CARRIER          : chr  "EV" "EV" "EV" "EV" ...
 $ TAIL_NUM         : chr  "N12530" "N15527" "N11526" "N28529" ...
 $ FL_NUM           : int  4524 4524 4524 4524 4524 4524 4524 4524 4524 4524 ...
 $ ORIGIN           : chr  "LFT" "LFT" "LFT" "LFT" ...
 $ ORIGIN_CITY_NAME : chr  "Lafayette, LA" "Lafayette, LA" "Lafayette, LA" "Lafayette, LA" ...
 $ ORIGIN_STATE_ABR : chr  "LA" "LA" "LA" "LA" ...
 $ ORIGIN_STATE_NM  : chr  "Louisiana" "Louisiana" "Louisiana" "Louisiana" ...
 $ DEST_AIRPORT_ID  : int  12266 12266 12266 12266 12266 12266 12266 12266 12266 12266 ...
 $ DEST             : chr  "IAH" "IAH" "IAH" "IAH" ...
 $ DEST_CITY_NAME   : chr  "Houston, TX" "Houston, TX" "Houston, TX" "Houston, TX" ...
 $ DEST_STATE_ABR   : chr  "TX" "TX" "TX" "TX" ...
 $ DEST_STATE_NM    : chr  "Texas" "Texas" "Texas" "Texas" ...
 $ DEP_TIME         : int  NA NA NA 636 959 700 654 656 651 656 ...
 $ DEP_DELAY        : num  NA NA NA -12 191 12 6 1 -9 1 ...
 $ ARR_TIME         : int  NA NA NA 733 1057 811 757 804 749 800 ...
 $ ARR_DELAY        : num  NA NA NA -23 181 15 1 2 -18 -2 ...
 $ CANCELLED        : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CANCELLATION_CODE: chr  "B" "B" "B" "" ...
 $ AIR_TIME         : num  NA NA NA 38 39 40 43 52 47 40 ...
 $ DISTANCE         : num  201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 201 ...
 $ CARRIER_DELAY    : num  NA NA NA NA 181 12 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ WEATHER_DELAY    : num  NA NA NA NA 0 0 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X                : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

class(df$FL_DATE)
[1] "character"
```

convert `FL_DATE` column to `Date` class,

```
df$FL_DATE<- as.Date(df$FL_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

#check class now
class(df$FL_DATE)
[1] "Date"
```